# Headphones input switch

Tags: headphones

In my workstation, the computer CPU (and the headphone jack) is inside the desk near the foot. Not very easy to reach to plug/unplug.

So I am looking for a solution that would allow me to switch the headphone input from the PC to my phone/ipod without messing with the plugs.

Ideally there would be a free 3.5mm male jack at my desk, and I'd plug it into whatever media device i brought, and switch the input from the PC to that one, not unlike a computer KVM switch.

For example, [this device does what I want](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HA11KFQ), but `4 in / 4 out` is too much. I just need `2 in / 1 out`.

It is the opposite of what [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000K8PH8C) does: The output is just the headphones (can't use speakers, company policy).

Answer (score 2):

[This Audio A/B switch](http://a.co/dKrP4QN) might be what you are looking for, because it provides exactly two inputs and one output as requested.

Since you plan to use it with standard 3.5" jacks, you will need these [extra cables](http://a.co/b9HLLrR) to connect the PC and smartphone jack sockets to the switch input sockets.

While those cables are required in your case, they are also useful to you, because they solve the problem of the PC providing a socket under the desk near the foot, because you can buy longer cables or jack extension cables.